# Disabling radio button selection for future if a user selected one time

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using four radio buttons on my Wordpress website.

If the user selects one radio button and clicks on submit button, then the user should not be able to change/select other option in future except admins.

I am using a lot of radio buttons on my website. So I want to apply this to

> .option-label .iradio_minimal

```js
$('input:checkbox').click(function() {
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox');
    if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
      $inputs.not(this).prop('disabled', true); // <-- disable all but checked one
    } else {
      $inputs.prop('disabled', false); // <--
    }
  }

)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="option_76" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_76" value="testing 1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 1
</label>

<label for="option_77" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_77" value="testing 2" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 2
</label>

<label for="option_78" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_78" value="testing 3" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 3
</label>

<label for="option_79" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_79" value="testing 4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 4
</label>
```

Comment: Please update your snippet with CSS to actually show the checkboxes

Answer (score 0):

You need to disable all the inputs in the submit event not on the input click event:

```js
$('form').on('submit',function(){
    var $inputs = $('input:checkbox');
    if($('input:checkbox:checked').length) { 
        $inputs.prop('disabled',true);//disable all if at least one is checked
    }
 })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label for="option_76" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_76" value="testing 1" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 1
</label>

<label for="option_77" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_77" value="testing 2" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 2
</label>

<label for="option_78" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_78" value="testing 3" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 3
</label>

<label for="option_79" class="option-label">
   <span class="iradio_minimal">
      <input type="radio" name="field_54" id="option_79" value="testing 4" style="position: absolute; opacity: 0;">
        <ins class="iCheck-helper" style="position: absolute; top: 0%; left: 0%; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%; margin: 0px; padding: 0px; background: rgb(255, 255, 255); border: 0px; opacity: 0; cursor: pointer;"></ins>
   </span>testing 4
</label>
```